# how to insert content to Ajax.ActionLink

Tags: asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

In Asp.net mvc3 razor I have:

```
Ajax.ActionLink("Hello world", "Hello", "Say", new RouteValueDictionary(new { word = "Hello" }),new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "GET", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace, UpdateTargetId = "dynamic-container" })
```

it produces

```
<a href="...." ...>Hello world</a>
```

What I would like to get is

```
<a href="..." ...><my><html><content/></html></my></a>
```

How can I pass "" so that it will be inserted instead of the standard text?

Comment: So you want to put html tags inside your ActionLink, something like: `Ajax.ActionLink("<span>Hello</span> world", "Hello", "Say", new RouteValueDictionary(new { word = "Hello" }),new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "GET", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace, UpdateTargetId = "dynamic-container" })` ?

Comment: can you post your controller action code

Comment: yes, I would like to do Ajax.ActionLink(..... and as a param somewhere add that html that will whow up inside <a></a>). As for the controller, it is irrelevant here. It returns a partial view that is inserted somwhere in the page

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I've just found a solution

http://forums.asp.net/post/4517653.aspx

It's not as elegant as I would expected but should do.

Anyone has a better idea?

Comment: This is what I was going to suggest, it seems the best way to create your own helper to do this

Comment: bit disappointing, hope They will add some elegant solution in MVC4 :)

Comment: Personally I find the whole helper thing not elegant, I mean there is something like 12 overloads for the Ajax.ActionLink method, thats horrible

Comment: the idea behind helpers is good imho, however it can be use unwisely :) and therefore I also consider it as "not elegant" as well ;)

Answer (score 0):

the code:

```
Ajax.ActionLink("Hello world", "Hello", "Say", new RouteValueDictionary(new { word = "Hello" }),new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "GET", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace, UpdateTargetId = "dynamic-container" })
```

with the link provided results in a error. The link looks like this:

```
.../Say/Hello?Count=1&Keys=System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary%602%2BKeyCollection%5BSystem.String%2CSystem.Object%5D&Values=System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary%602%2BValueCollection%5BSystem.String%2CSystem.Object%5D
```

which is BAAADDDDD....  the issue is that this uses the wrong overload. Instead of:

```
new RouteValueDictionary(new { word = "Hello" })
```

where should be:

```
 new { word = "Hello" }
```

when the code form the link in a previous answer works like a charm - hope it'll be helpful for somebody, anybody

Answer (score 0):

You can use javascript / jQuery to force an insert into the item after rendering. This may be a bit 'quick and dirty' but it does get the job done without too much effort.

Attach a class using the HtmlAttributes object for each `@Ajax.Action` to allow you to select them later using JS:

```
@Ajax.ActionLink(.....  new { @class = "AjaxLink btn btn-primary" })
```

Then use javascript / jQuery to find the link(s) by class, and replace the innerHTML of each. The following is a jQuery example, it could also be written in plain javascript. I personally like the jQuery was as it's more concise:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//hack to insert a <span> inside the remove links so that the text can be styled                
$('.AjaxLink ).html('<i class="fa fa-minus-circle"></i><span class="ActionLinkText">Your Text here</span>');

</script>
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

The solution @4rchie pointing of using helper method is the best solution. But there is another way which keeps the data to be inserted with the link using a data-* attribute and use jquery to do rest of the work.

For example:

```
<div class="list-group">
@foreach (var item in Model.Things)
{
   @Ajax.ActionLink(item.Name, "actionName", "controllerName", new { Id = item.Id }, new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "GET", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace, UpdateTargetId = "areaPanel", OnComplete = "" }, new { @class = "list-group-item", data_frequency = item.frequency})

}
</div>
```

Jquery code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
$("[data-frequency]").each(function () {
        var linkText = $(this).html();
        var attr = $(this).attr("data-frequency");
        $(this).html("<span class ='badge'>" + attr + "</span>" + linkText);
})
}
```

The result is like http://getbootstrap.com/components/#list-group-badges